# Invoice Ninja container not starting up successfully

Tags: docker, podman, invoice-ninja

I'd like to try invoice ninja and I'm deploying it on an Alpine 3.17 host running podman. I have plenty of other pods running there already so there is no general problem.

What I did:

- On my dedicated MySQL host I prepared an empty DB with a user and made sure the user can connect from the the podman host.
- Prepared two directories:

  - /opt/dockervol/invoiceninja/libcom/public and
  - /opt/dockervol/invoiceninja/libcom/storage
    /opt/dockervol/invoiceninja/ is owned by 1500:1500

Then I try to run with the following command:

```
  podman run -d \
  -v /opt/dockervol/invoiceninja/libcom/public:/var/app/public \
  -v /opt/dockervol/invoiceninja/libcom/storage:/var/app/storage \
  -e APP_ENV='production' \
  -e APP_DEBUG=0 \
  -e APP_URL='http://example.com' \
  -e APP_KEY='a key that I generated like the docs tell' \
  -e APP_CIPHER='AES-256-CBC' \
  -e DB_TYPE='mysql' \
  -e DB_STRICT='false' \
  -e DB_HOST='db.example.com' \
  -e DB_DATABASE='invoiceninja' \
  -e DB_USERNAME='invoiceninja' \
  -e DB_PASSWORD='myuserpassword' \
  -p '8415:80' \
  --network podmannet \
  invoiceninja/invoiceninja
```

No service is actually listening on 8415 on the docker host and even when I run /bin/sh in the container and look with netstat, only one service is running on 9000.

This is what the logs say:

```
2023-03-29T19:48:57Z [INFO] [Entrypoint]: Initialising Invoice Ninja...

   INFO  Configuration cached successfully.  


   INFO  Caching the framework bootstrap files.  

  config ........................................................... 18ms DONE
  routes ........................................................... 32ms DONE


   INFO  Nothing to migrate.  

2023-03-29 19:48:58,550 WARN For [program:php-fpm], redirect_stderr=true but stderr_logfile has also been set to a filename, the filename has been ignored
2023-03-29 19:48:58,550 WARN For [program:scheduler], redirect_stderr=true but stderr_logfile has also been set to a filename, the filename has been ignored
2023-03-29 19:48:58,550 WARN For [program:queue-worker], redirect_stderr=true but stderr_logfile has also been set to a filename, the filename has been ignored
2023-03-29 19:48:58,550 WARN For [program:queue-worker], redirect_stderr=true but stderr_logfile has also been set to a filename, the filename has been ignored
2023-03-29 19:48:58,551 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2023-03-29 19:48:59,553 INFO spawned: 'shutdown' with pid 53
2023-03-29 19:48:59,554 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 54
2023-03-29 19:48:59,555 INFO spawned: 'queue-worker_00' with pid 55
2023-03-29 19:48:59,556 INFO spawned: 'queue-worker_01' with pid 56
2023-03-29 19:48:59,556 INFO spawned: 'scheduler' with pid 57
READY
[29-Mar-2023 19:48:59] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[29-Mar-2023 19:48:59] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[29-Mar-2023 19:48:59] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[29-Mar-2023 19:48:59] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[29-Mar-2023 19:48:59] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 54
[29-Mar-2023 19:48:59] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.  

2023-03-29 19:49:01,213 INFO success: shutdown entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-03-29 19:49:01,213 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-03-29 19:49:01,213 INFO success: queue-worker_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-03-29 19:49:01,213 INFO success: queue-worker_01 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-03-29 19:49:01,213 INFO success: scheduler entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
  2023-03-29 19:50:00 Running [queue-size-job] ...................... 5ms DONE
  2023-03-29 19:50:00 Running [Callback] ............................ 9ms DONE

   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.  

   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.  

   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.  

   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.  

  2023-03-29 19:55:00 Running [queue-size-job] ...................... 4ms DONE
  2023-03-29 19:55:00 Running [Callback] ............................ 8ms DONE

   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.
```

Could someone please point me into the right direction.

Thank your

Comment: Which bit of the logs are the error? All those messages seem to indicate success to me (I have no idea what "invoice ninja" is though)

Comment: I cannot spot errors either, but the service just isn't working at all.

Comment: It seems like this container does not have any type of webservice embedded. To me it seems really hard to deploy Invoice Ninja via Docker.